# Pop ups for pictures in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 radio buttons on my form suggesting
3 different pictures to choose from and I have one 
picture box in which these pictures will appear.
How do I create pop ups with different information for
each of the pictures in one text box when the mouse
hovers on top of the image and disappears 
when the mouse leaves? How?

I've tried and tried Googling but nothing has 
helped me at all.

Comment: Is this for vb.net or Android? What have you tried? (Assuming vb.net) Have you looked at the mouse events on the picturebox control?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? I need to know that to choose the right dupe target...